# How to reflect changes to a pointer to the caller

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, queue

I am currently trying to implement a queue data structure using a linked list of structs. Currently, I have a node struct for the linked list:

```
struct Node { int data; struct Node *next; };
```

and I also have an insert, delete, and display functions to change/access the queue. Here are their signatures:

```
void insert(int, struct Node*, struct Node*);
void delete(struct Node*);
void display(struct Node*);
```

I am having trouble with reflecting changes made by those functions to the queue. in my main function, I declare two Node pointers as such:

```
struct Node *front = NULL;
struct Node *rear = NULL;
```

which I am using to keep track of the front and rear nodes in the queue. I passed them into the functions as can be seen above. When doing all that, it seems that the front pointer never gets updated, and stays NULL even after my functions are called, so display and delete never really work, and insert does not reflect additions made.

However, when I declare my struct as such:

```
struct Node { int data; struct Node *next; } *front = NULL, *rear = NULL;
```

and I don't pass in any arguments that are `Node*`, it all works fine. Why is that?

EDIT: I don't think I specified, but I am trying to NOT use the second version of my struct; I don't want the front/rear Node pointers declared globally (I think that is what it is called).

Comment: So what I am seeing is that I must use either a double pointer, or return a Node pointer in order to deal with passing in the Node pointer to my functions? (And thanks for the link to old post, I should look better next time)

Comment: Your observations are correct. If you have your solution, you can always confirm that the previous question solves your problem, and it will close your question automatically.

Comment: Sounds good; sorry to keep asking questions, but where do you confirm that?

Comment: Use the debugger.

Comment: Should be up there somewhere at the top of the post. If it isn't, that's okay. It will undoubtedly be closed by the community any way soon.